# MATLAB 2D randperm with no for loop

Tags: matlab, random, permutation

I want to make a 2D array of random permutations where each row may contain a number that was generated in a previous row. But there cannot be the same number in the same row.

Is there anyway to do the following code with no for loop?

```
a = (1:100);
b = zeros(size(a,2), 4);
for i = 1:size(a, 2)
     r = randperm(size(a, 2),4);
     b(i,:) = r;
end
```

Comment: Have you thought about implementing a recursive solution? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No this isn't homework. Would doing this recursively make it more efficient?

Comment: Not sure, in my experience I find a well designed loop is usually quicker in Matlab. So the solution could involve a loop but you are also open to other suggestions?

Comment: Yeah what other suggestions?

Comment: Seems pretty efficient to me, why does it need to be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

The following approach can be used if you are not memory-limited (it generates an intermediate "100"-column matrix when only "4" columns are actually needed):

1. Generate full permutations. This is done easily with the first output of [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) (mimicking how `randperm` was coded in old Matlab versions).
2. Trim to the desired number of columns.

Code:

```
a = 1:100;
n = 4;
[~, result] = sort(rand(numel(a)),2);   %// step 1
result = result(:, 1:n);                %// step 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A not-so efficient way (mostly because of the sorting) that would produce similar results is:

```
[dummy, idx] = sort(rand(100, 4));
b = idx';
```

As pointed out, this produces an array `b` with rows of non-repeating elements, but it has 4 rows and 100 columns instead of the opposite. Follow Luis's solution instead.

Comment: But this doesn't prevent repeated numbers in the same row

Comment: I think that `idx`s columns don't have repeated numbers. Isn't that so?

Comment: Try the following several times: `[dummy, idx] = sort(rand(10, 4))` (10 instead of 100 to increase probability of repeated number)

Comment: I'm not talking about the rows, I'm talking about the columns. A column cannot have repeating numbers since it describes a permutation of the original column to produce its sorted version. That's why `b` is assigned `idx`'s transpose.

Comment: Try `[dummy, idx] = sort(rand(10, 4)); b = idx'` several times and you'll find the same number twice in the same column

Comment: Let me say it again: I am talking about `idx`s columns. After `b` is assigned the transpose, its rows become `idx`s columns which are unique. `b`s columns of course are not unique. You are checking `idx`s rows for non-uniqueness, which I have already acknowledged.

Comment: From [sort's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html). "If you sort the columns of a matrix , then the above relation holds for each column independently. That is, each column of I is a permutation vector of the corresponding column of A". But, a permutation vector of any column has, by definition, no repeating numbers. So any of idx's columns is a permutation vector, which becomes a row of b. There might be 2 identical rows (especially in smaller dimensions), but each of them will not have repeating elements. Only Luis's solution avoids the case of 2 identical rows.

Comment: The OP wants no repeated numbers along the dimension-of-size-4 (his rows of `b`, your columns of `b`). Maybe part of the confusion is that you generate `b` as 4x100, whereas the OP generates it as 100x4

Comment: @VHarisop That is, no group of 4 numbers should have repeated members

Comment: @Luis Indeed. My apologies for the confusion. I think that in this case, my solution would work by adding a `reshape(b, 100, 4)`, since each pack of 4 elements would be picked from the same row of `b`.

Comment: Adding `b = reshape(b, 100, 4)` doesn't avoid repetitions. Try with 10 instead of 100 and you'll see. To avoid repetitions I think you need to generate a size-100 permutation (as in my answer), even though you'll only use 4 of those 100 elements

Comment: `reshape(idx', 10, 4)` won't work because 4 is not a divisor of 10. I think it will work for `reshape(idx', 100, 4)` because then no elements for any row of 4 will have to be picked from separate columns of `idx` (thus eliminating the possibility of duplicates).
But my solution is problematic anyway since it does not work for any desired dimension.